# Kivy RecycleView: Get indices of all data items that are currently in view

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I need to get the indices of all data items that are currently in view in a Kivy RecycleView widget. I want to display many Image widgets for which I render a texture and apply it to them. To save memory I need to delete these textures if they are not in view any more. I tried using the [Kivy RecycleView example](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html) and modify it for my needs:

```
class SelectableImage(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Image):
    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        #Catch and handle the view changes
        #print in view
        print(index)
        #call initial function of image class
        return super(SelectableImage, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)
```

The problem here is that refresh_view_attrs() only fires when a new Image widget gets added to the view. Thus I can only know what that last Image is, but not if there are any other in view. For this I'd also need to know which widget disappeared from the view. Is there any function in the RecycleView widget that I can use to obtain such information? Maybe there is a function that gets called whenever the view changes?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I found three possible solutions for my issue:

### 1. Solution

Calculate the position of all the Image widgets yourself and compare it with the position of the scrollbar to get the widgets that are currently displayed. 
This is quite hacky and the RecycleView already does this internally. Thus I'd save the unnecessary computing and avoid this approach.

### 2. Solution

Use the get_visible_view(index) function of the view_adapter property of a RecycleView. This returns the currently visible view associated with index. If it return None, the view associated with index is not visible right now. This is how it's called for example:

```
self.myRecycleView.view_adapter.get_visible_view(index)
```

You could loop through the entire length of your data list and check for each item (the index in the list) if it is currently displayed or not.

### 3. Solution

My favourite approach: Use get_view_index_at(pos) of the layout_manager property to check what view index is at the given coordinates. This way you could check which item is at the top of the RecycleLayout widget and which one is at the bottom. You need to use coordinate transformation though. Example:

```
#get position at top center of RecycleView (upper limit)
pos = self.myRecycleView.to_local(self.myRecycleView.center_x, self.myRecycleView.height)
#check which items collides with the given position    
print(self.myRecycleView.layout_manager.get_view_index_at(pos))
```

I hope this clears some things up!

Comment: In your profile, it says "Last seen more than 5 years ago" so you will probably never see this, but you made my life much easier with this goated comment. Thanks!